# EndlessAdapter issue

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm trying to adopt endless adapter. There's an activity - say ClipsActivity it extends abstract class which extends Activity. In some examples I've seen that Activity is extended from ListActivity - is it crucial? I also have a list adapter which extends base adapter, while in examples ArrayAdapter is used. When I get to the end of the list I get an error(log below)

Would you mind point what the problem might be and whether there're uncertainties in this way of implementing of Endless ? Additionaly I would appreciate links on thorough examples. I've seen demo - but it's not enough clear for me.
Thanks.

My activity

```
public class ClipsActivity extends AbstractActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.clips);

            _init();
            ListView clipList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clipList);
            EndlessClipListAdapter endlessClipsList = new EndlessClipListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), new ClipListAdapter(this, _getClips()), R.id.downloadBar);
            clipList.setAdapter(endlessClipsList);
        } catch (HTTPFactoryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My endlessadapter

```
public class EndlessClipListAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {

    private RotateAnimation rotate=null;

    public EndlessClipListAdapter(Context context, ListAdapter wrapped, int pendingResource) {
        super(context, wrapped, pendingResource);
        rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 
                0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(600);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws Exception {
        SystemClock.sleep(10000);
        return(getWrappedAdapter().getCount()<14);
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendCachedData() {
        if (getWrappedAdapter().getCount()<14) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
        //View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        View child=row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        child.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        child.startAnimation(rotate);

        return(row);
      }

}
```

LogCat

```
04-20 13:41:43.083: W/dalvikvm(480): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 15
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at ru.localhost.xxxx.android.view.ClipListAdapter.getItemId(ClipListAdapter.java:47)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.commonsware.cwac.adapter.AdapterWrapper.getItemId(AdapterWrapper.java:127)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(AdapterView.java:745)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.AdapterView.setSelectedPositionInt(AdapterView.java:1088)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.ListView.arrowScrollImpl(ListView.java:2324)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.ListView.arrowScroll(ListView.java:2287)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.ListView.commonKey(ListView.java:2089)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.ListView.onKeyDown(ListView.java:2036)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1256)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3855)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:787)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.widget.ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(ListView.java:2021)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:789)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2073)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1663)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2560)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2535)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-20 13:41:43.093: E/AndroidRuntime(480):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

> In some examples I've seen that Activity is extended from ListActivity - is it crucial?

No. You are welcome to use a `ListFragment`, or a plain activity with a `ListView`.

> I also have a list adapter which extends base adapter, while in examples ArrayAdapter is used.

The adapter needs to support the concept of appending additional data. `ArrayAdapter` does; `CursorAdapter` does not. I cannot say whether your adapter will or will not.

> Would you mind point what the problem might be

I do not know for certain. The fact that your `appendCachedData()` is not actually appending anything would be a likely candidate. Please read [the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) and follow its instructions.

> Additionaly I would appreciate links on thorough examples.

There is the `demo/` sub-project [in the repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

> I've seen demo - but it's not enough clear for me.

There are other implementations of this pattern elsewhere; perhaps one of those components will be better suited for you.